# Multiple objects tracking using Extended Kalman Filter Matlab

Tags: matlab, object, kalman-filter

I want to track multiple objects in *3D space*, however I wrote a `classdef` for visual tracking of an object using *Extended Kalman Filter* in *Matalb*. It working is fine for a single object object. However I want to track multiple objects of same *3D space* and call this class in external nested `for` loops. All what I'm misunderstanding/confusing is that, how to call this in external loops to know the predicted value of every object. I have the `Constructor` in which assumptions and initializing of variables are defined,  and in my understanding it must be initialized once for every object, not in every loop iteration.

How to initialize this for every object and get the predicted value. The assumptions/constructor can only be  defined outside the class as it assumes the first 2 rows of an object.

Please help me to get out of this, its so confusing for me.

**My External Loops:**

```
for ii = i:1000  % position of objects
for jj = 1:5 %5 objects
predictedS = EKF(obj{jj}(ii,:));
predictedS=predictedS.EKFpredictor;
end
```

**My Extended Kalman Filter:**

```
classdef EKF <handle
    properties (Access=private)
        H
        K
        Z
        Q
        M
        ind
        A
        X
        Xh
        P
        a
        b
    end
    methods
        function obj = EKF(position)
            obj.H = [];
            obj.K = [];
            obj.Z  = [];
            obj.ind=0; % indicator function. Used for unwrapping of tan
            obj.Q =[0 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 0 0 0.01 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 0.01 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 0.01];% Covarience matrix of process noise
            obj.M=[0.001 0 0;
                0 0.001 0;
                0 0 0.001]; % Covarience matrix of measurment noise
            obj.A=[1 0 0 0.1 0 0;
                0 1 0 0 0.1 0;
                0 0 1 0 0 0.1;
                0 0 0 1 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 1 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 1]; % System Dynamics
            obj.X(:,1)=position(1:6,1); % Actual initial conditions
            obj.Z(:,:,1)=position(1,:)';% initial observation
            obj.Xh(:,1)=position(1:6,1);%Assumed initial conditions
            obj.P(:,:,1)=[0.1 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 0.1 0 0 0 0;
                0 0 0.1 0 0 0;
                0 0 0 0.1 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 0.1 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 0.1]; %inital value of covarience of estimation error

        end

        function predictedS=EKFpredictor(obj)
            function   [ARG]=arctang(a,b,ind)
                if b<0 && a>0 % PLACING IN THE RIGHT QUADRANT
                    ARG=abs(atan(a/b))+pi/2;
                elseif b<0 && a<0
                    ARG=abs(atan(a/b))+pi;
                elseif b>0 && a<0
                    ARG=abs(atan(a/b))+3*pi/2;
                else
                    ARG=atan(a/b);
                end
                if ind==-1 % UNWARPPING PART
                    ARG=ARG-2*pi;
                else
                    if ind==1;
                        ARG=ARG+2*pi;
                    end
                end
            end

            for n = 1:100
            obj.X(:,n+1)=obj.A*obj.X(:,n)+[0;0;0;sqrt(obj.Q(4,4))*randn(1);sqrt(obj.Q(5,5))*randn(1);sqrt(obj.Q(6,6))*randn(1)];
            obj.Z(:,n+1)=[sqrt(obj.X(1,n)^2+obj.X(2,n)^2);arctang(obj.X(2,n),obj.X(1,n),obj.ind);obj.X(3,n)]+[sqrt(obj.M(1,1))*randn(1);sqrt(obj.M(1,1))*randn(1);sqrt(obj.M(1,1))*randn(1)];
            obj.Xh(:,n+1)=obj.A*obj.Xh(:,n);
            predictedS=obj.Xh';
            obj.P(:,:,n+1)=obj.A*obj.P(:,:,n)*obj.A'+obj.Q;
            obj.H(:,:,n+1)=[obj.Xh(1,n+1)/(sqrt(obj.Xh(1,n+1)^2+obj.Xh(2,n+1)^2)), obj.Xh(2,n+1)/(sqrt(obj.Xh(1,n+1)^2+obj.Xh(2,n+1)^2)),0,0,0,0; ...
                -obj.Xh(2,n+1)/(sqrt(obj.Xh(1,n+1)^2+obj.Xh(2,n+1)^2)), obj.Xh(1,n+1)/(sqrt(obj.Xh(1,n+1)^2+obj.Xh(2,n+1)^2)),0,0,0,0; ...
                0,0,1,0,0,0];
            obj.K(:,:,n+1)=obj.P(:,:,n+1)*obj.H(:,:,n+1)'*(obj.M+obj.H(:,:,n+1)*obj.P(:,:,n+1)*obj.H(:,:,n+1)')^(-1);
            Inov=obj.Z(:,n+1)-[sqrt(obj.Xh(1,n+1)^2+obj.Xh(2,n+1)^2);arctang(obj.Xh(2,n+1),obj.Xh(1,n+1),obj.ind);obj.Xh(3,n+1)];
            obj.Xh(:,n+1)=obj.Xh(:,n+1)+ obj.K(:,:,n+1)*Inov;
            obj.P(:,:,n+1)=(eye(6)-obj.K(:,:,n+1)*obj.H(:,:,n+1))*obj.P(:,:,n+1);
            theta1=arctang(obj.Xh(1,n+1),obj.Xh(2,n+1),0);
            theta=arctang(obj.Xh(1,n),obj.Xh(2,n),0);
            if abs(theta1-theta)>=pi
                if obj.ind==1
                    obj.ind=0;
                else
                    obj.ind=1;
                end
            end
            end
        end

    end
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is working fine for a single object, then you could create an array of Kalman filters for each object that you are tracking.  That way, the EKF is associated with a single object and not with a group (since the state and covariance matrices, `X` and `P` respectively are specific for a single object that has been predicted (and later corrected/updated?) with some observation.

I'm a little unclear on what your double loops are - presumably you just have five objects and 1000 observations for each, so you could do something like the following

```
% there are 5 objects
numObjs = 5;

% initialize a cell array of EKFs
ekfs = cell(numObjs,1);

% initialize the EKF (tracker) for each object given the first observation
for i=1:numObjs
    ekfs{i} = EKF(obj{i}(1,:));  % so get the first obs for object i
end

% now predict and correct each object with the new observation (new position of object)
for j=2:1000
    for i=1:numObjs
        ekfs{i} = ekfs{i}.EKFpredictor(obj{i}(j,:));
    end
end
```

The above will conflict with your code for two reasons - the `EKFpredictor` is being passed a new position (rather then re-creating a new EKF) and the return value from this function is being re-assigned to the cell array (so that we always maintain the most up-to-date version of the EKF for that object).  That means your function signature must change to

```
function [obj,predictedS]=EKFpredictor(obj,position)
```

The new position is being passed because presumably you are using the previous iteration's position and correcting (or updating) it given the new one.  The EKF's state and covariance (`X` and `P`) are to be updated with the new measurement state and covariance (usually denoted by `Z` and `R`).  I noticed that you have the `Z` but not the `R` (that could be your `M`?).

But then in the `EKFPredictor` method, the code iterates 100 times - why is that?

I don't see any explicit prediction in the `EKFPredictor` method with a transition matrix `F` and a time delta between the previous update and the current one. Is that not anything you have to be concerned with, or is it just hidden?

I'm hoping that the above is somewhat helpful though it may be not what you are expecting.  But you do have to create separate EKFs for each object.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I'v nested loops in which the outer loop iterates position of object and the inner one is for iterating objects, i.e for every position value, every object should be in action. And yes, `M` is my Covarience matrix of measurment noise. I'v created for one object only, so I'v used a `for` loop of `100` but now this must be excluded, and how can I input `n` with respect to my outter loop?

Comment: I'm still unclear on what `n` is exactly - it is the number of observations for an object?  If so, why does the outer loop iterate 1000 times?  As an aside, what is your state matrix X - is it a 2D position and velocity, 3D, etc.?  What is your observation input?  Another 2D or 3D position?

Comment: Im sorry for the unclearness, `n` is number of observations same as the outer loop `ii`. I want to input an observation `ii`  instead of `n` taking the prediction and then again input that previous position. must be `n=ii` and eliminates for loop of `n`. A 3D position only.

Comment: `function [obj,predictedS]=EKFpredictor(obj,position)` in the function signature, I want to give `ii` and `position(ii)` and output the same.

Comment: Cool about the `n` being the same as the outer loop.  You shouldn't need to pass in both the `ii` and the `position(ii)` unless you are using the index to keep track of the state and covariance at each update (a history).

Comment: I didn't understand your point, how to pass and update the position at every point? please clarify this regarding my code.

Comment: At each iteration of the outer loop, you will now pass in just the observation (new 3D position) for the object to be used to update the object's current `X` and `P`.  Unless you still want to instantiate the object with ALL 100 (or 1000) positions?

Comment: U mean to say my functino signature should b like this `function [obj,predictedS]=EKFpredictor(obj,position(ii,:))` and What about `n` ?

Comment: No - the function signature remains as `[obj,predictedS]=EKFpredictor(obj,position)` but when you call it from your loop, you will want something like `[ekfs{i},predictedS] = ekfs{i}.EKFpredictor(objectArray{i}(j,:));` where you are passing in JUST the new position (or however you access that single position on the jth iteration of the `for` loop - I don't know what that structure looks like).  Note that I renamed the cell array of five objects (with their observations) to `objectArray` to make it clear that this is different from the `obj` that is used in your class definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55735/discussion-between-user3593525-and-geoff-hayes).